# nodeJS - nodemon console log stopped working

Tags: javascript, node.js, console.log, pm2, nodemon

I am having a weird problem, suddenly the nodemon stopped showing console log.

I am using **`npm run dev`** command to run the nodeJS app and my **`package.json`** looks like below,

```
{
  "name": "loginform",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "dev": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.1.4",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "body-parser-xml": "^1.1.0",
    "cassandra-driver": "^3.1.6",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "ejs": "^2.0.6",
    "es6-template-strings": "^2.0.1",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "express-rate-limit": "^2.6.0",
    "express-session": "^1.10.1",
    "log-buffer": "0.0.3",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.25",
    "mongoose": "^4.7.0",
    "nodemailer": "^0.7.1",
    "passport": "^0.2.1",
    "passport-facebook": "^1.0.3",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-twitter": "^1.0.2",
    "qs": "^6.3.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^6.5.5",
    "trim": "0.0.1",
    "url-pattern": "^1.0.3",
    "uuid": "^3.0.1",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0"
  }
}
```

I was working but suddenly stopped working, I am able to figure out why, though I had installed [pm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2) in between but uninstalled, is this the cause that might have broken the logging?

**Update**

This is how my console looks, no log at all.

[image]

Can anyone help with a solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You had a typo. I am sure you run this via `npm run dev`.

Try removing your node_modules folder, and re run `npm install`

Comment: Yes, I mentioned it in my question.

Comment: You actually wrote `npm dev run`, please correct it.

Comment: Yes, that was typo.

Comment: I am using correct command while running, I mistakenly wrote wrong command in question.

Comment: Try removing your `node_modules` folder, and re run npm install

Comment: if it still does not work for you can you add console output?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140101/discussion-between-iphonic-and-loelsonk).

Comment: Reinstallation didn't work, I have added console screenshot in the question.